# PHP - spatie/image-optimizer doesn't work

Tags: php

I try to optimize images on PHP, and after some search, I found this library on GitHub `spatie/image-optimizer`.

I downloaded it using composer, and I following tho code

```
use Spatie\ImageOptimizer\OptimizerChainFactory;
$optimizerChain = OptimizerChainFactory::create();
$optimizerChain->optimize("images/test.jpg", "images/test2.jpg");
```

but, I receive the test2 without any modification or optimization, can I know the problem?

PS: I use images from the net, and the images founded on documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the necessary binaries. Follow the instructions below:
https://github.com/spatie/image-optimizer/blob/master/README.md

Comment: So what were you missing?